# Dart Streams - How to combine previous and next element?

Tags: dart, stream

I have a simple widget subscribed to a Stream of elements.

Each time a new element is received I would like to get also the previous element and decide which one of them pass downstream.

Currently I am using the `map` operator to store the previous element and calculate the next, like this:

```
elements.map((e) {
 if (this.previous == null) {
  this.previous = e;
  return e;
 } 

 final next = merge(this.previous, e);

 this.previous = e;
 return next;
}).listen(...);
```

How can I do this better and avoid having `this.previous`?

Comment: Do you have the full List prior to running the code?  Of what type is `elements`?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [rxdart package](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart/install) there is an extension method called [pairwise](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/PairwiseExtension/pairwise.html) which according to the documentation:

> Emits the n-th and n-1th events as a pair. The first event won't be emitted until the second one arrives.

Then you should be able to do something along the lines of this:

```dart
elements.pairwise().map((pair) => merge(pair.first, pair.last)).listen(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility

```dart
void main() {
  List list = [12, 24, 48, 60];
  list.reduce((value, element) {
    print(value + element); // Push to another list maybe?
    return element;
  });
}
```

If you are working with a stream try this

```dart
void main() {
  var counterStream = Stream<int>.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (x) => x)
       .reduce((previous, element) {
          print(previous + element); // Push to another stream maybe?
          return element;
  });
}
```